# Implementing covariant interface multiple times: is this behavior properly defined?

Tags: c#, covariance

Given the following covariant generic interface

```
public interface IContainer<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

We can create a class that implements this interface multiple times for multiple generic types. In the scenario I'm interested about, these generic types share a common base type.

```
public interface IPrint
{
    void Print();
}
public class PrintA : IPrint
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
public class PrintB : IPrint
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

public class SuperContainer : IContainer<PrintA>, IContainer<PrintB>
{
    PrintA IContainer<PrintA>.Value => new PrintA();
    PrintB IContainer<PrintB>.Value => new PrintB();
}
```

Now things get interesting when using this class through a reference of type `IContainer<IPrint>`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IContainer<IPrint> container = new SuperContainer();
    container.Value.Print();
}
```

This compiles and runs without issue and prints "A". What I've found in the [spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664592(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The implementation of a particular interface member I.M, where I is
>   the interface in which the member M is declared, is determined by
>   examining each class or struct S, starting with C and repeating for
>   each successive base class of C, until a match is located:
>
> - If S
>     contains a declaration of an explicit interface member implementation
>     that matches I and M, then this member is the implementation of I.M.
> - Otherwise, if S contains a declaration of a non-static public member
>     that matches M, then this member is the implementation of I.M.

The first bullet point appears to be relevant, because the interface implementations are explicit. However, it doesn't say anything about which implementation is selected when there are multiple candidates.

It gets even more interesting if we use a public poperty for the `IContainer<PrintA>` implementation:

```
public class SuperContainer : IContainer<PrintA>, IContainer<PrintB>
{
    public PrintA Value => new PrintA();
    PrintB IContainer<PrintB>.Value => new PrintB();
}
```

Now, according to above spec, because there is an explicit interface implementation through `IContainer<PrintB>`, I would expect this to print "B". However, it is instead using the public property and still printing "A".

Similarly, if instead I implement `IContainer<PrintA>` explicitely and `IContainer<PrintB>` through public property, it still prints "A".

It appears that the only thing the output depends on is the order in which the interfaces are declared. If I change the declaration to

```
public class SuperContainer : IContainer<PrintB>, IContainer<PrintA>
```

everything prints "B"!

Which part of the spec defines this behavior, if it is properly defined at all?

Comment: I would think that it is specified somewhere but I'm not seeing it. Eric Lippert had a [bleg](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/09/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-ten-dealing-with-ambiguity/) a long time ago, so someone was thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find it in the specification, but what you're seeing is expected. `IContainer<PrintA>` and `IContainer<PrintB>` have different Fully Qualified Names (unable to find spec on how this FQN is formed) and so the compiler recognizes `SuperContainer` as an implementing class of two different interfaces, each having a `void Print();` method.

So, we have two different interfaces each containing a method with the same signature. As you linked in the [spec (13.4.2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664592(v=vs.71).aspx) the implementation of `Print()` is chosen first by looking at `IContainer<PrintA>`, looking for a proper mapping, and *then* looking at `IContainer<PrintB>`.

Since a proper mapping was found in `IContainer<PrintA>`, `IContainer<PrintA>.Print()` is used in `SuperContainer`'s implimentation of `IContainer<PrintB>`.

From that same spec (located at the very bottom):

> The members of a base class participate in interface mapping. In the example

```
interface Interface1
{
   void F();
}
class Class1
{
   public void F() {}
   public void G() {}
}
class Class2: Class1, Interface1
{
   new public void G() {}
}
```

> the method F in Class1 is used in Class2's implementation of Interface1.

So in the end, yes the order is determining which `Print()` method is called.

Comment: Exactly from which text in the spec are you able to derive "the implementation of Print() is chosen first by looking at `IContainer<PrintA>`, looking for a proper mapping, and _then_ looking at `IContainer<PrintB>`."?